# how to remove space between records in table in report viewer in c#

Tags: c#

I have a C# billing application which prints bill in Report viewer with items purchased detail. but problem is  that there is lot of space between records which consume lot of paper.any one have idea how to reduce space between rows displaying items purchased.

Comment: a preview of how it looks ? what have you tried yourself ? including your code would help.

Comment: how can i add screen shot of my form here?